# Moment.toDate check if minutes are either 30 or 00

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, formatting, momentjs

Not entirely sure on how to check to see if the minutes in the start and end date are of the correct format. I want to send an alert if they are not withing 30 minute increments.

Here is what i have for invalid times when the end date is before the start date, i just want to add an else if to check for this. Im quite new to jquery and could use some help, thanks in advance!

Here is my cshtml js code:

```
var startDate = moment($('#txtStart').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
var endDate = moment($('#txtEnd').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
if (startDate > endDate) {
    alert('Invalid end date');
    return;
}
    //this is wrong
else if(startDate.Hours != '00' || startDate.Hours != '30' || endDate.Hours != '00' || endDate.Hours != '30'){
    alert('booking times must start or end in 30 minute increments')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get minutes of duration between start to end time like this:

```
var duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));
var minutes = duration.asMinutes();
```

Then you can check your conditions. Please see [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) for more information.

Comment: tyvm ! I am very new so this was a huge help!

Comment: @DominicMazur Please accept this answer, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.